# Looking for the right framework to implement an enterprise document management and analysis system

Tags: nlp, frameworks, document, analysis, enterprise

I have already spent quite some time with literature reviews and Google searches, but I didn't find anything suitable, yet.

The task is to implement a flexible and scalable enterprise document management and analysis system. I guess that represents a prototypical use case for many businesses.

The perfect framework would allow on premises operation (only Azure would be an option) and provide a low-code platform that allows to receive, tag and register documents (PDFs, Word and Excel files, other text files), indexing and smart search within and across documents and document collections, plus an interface to implement NLP tasks with Python.

Moreover, it would be benefitial, if this framework also would allow to model meta data about documents and about the business processes they are embedded in (for example, to check and verify completeness of a set of necessary documents, before further processing gets triggered).

I thought about a combination of Elastic Search and a NoSql Database like Cassandra, but that would not fit the low-code requirement.

You might call me naive, but I supposed that there ought to be trillions of such frameworks, as this is such a typical use case in terms of business automation. But I did not find the right framework, yet. I hope someone can provide hints.

Summary:

A document management and analysis framework that features:

- Enterprise-ready (on premises or compatible with Microsoft Azure)
- Low-code framework
- Large-scale document management and analysis
- Modular and extensible via Python and NLP models
- Connectable to business logics (i.e. checks for completeness of document collections)
- Allowing for meta data and smart search within and across documents

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Haystack](https://github.com/deepset-ai/haystack) which is being used by Airbus. It can easily be self-hosted and customized via a YAML file. It can fulfill the following requirements -

- Enterprise-ready (on-premises or compatible with Microsoft Azure)
- Low-code framework
- Large-scale document management and analysis
- Modular and extensible via Python and NLP models
- Allowing for metadata and smart search within and across documents

Following requirement currently not possible -

- Connectable to business logics (i.e. checks for completeness of document collections)

Tagging [@julian-risch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16897136/julian-risch) who can provide more information.